# Umbraco Razor - Pass Array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, umbraco7

I have a foreach loop in Razor which takes images from the Multiple Media Picker in Umbraco. The Response.Write just allows me to see that the images are displaying fine (which they are) so you can ignore this bit.

My question is, how do I populate the image tag with the image URL using the Javascript function? (see below which currently doesn't work).

Razor View/CSHTML

```
var imagesList = portfolioItem.GetPropertyValue<string>("Images").Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var imagesCollection = Umbraco.TypedMedia(imagesList);

foreach (var imageItem in imagesCollection)
{   
    Response.Write("<img src='"+ @imageItem.Url +"' />");
}
```

Javascript

```
openInfoWindow = function (name, imagesCollection, location, mw, url, marker) {
    var infoText = "<img src='" + imagesCollection + "' alt='" + imagesCollection + "'title='" + imagesCollection + "' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery, if u use razor to set the url as an invisible input value. Then use jquery to pull that value out and add it to the img tag itself by using the following:
var inputVal = $("input").val();
$("#my_image").attr("src",inputVal );

if you put the invisble input value as a variable you can set the img atr ursing jquery like I've shown above.

Comment: Great idea but it's only taking the first image in the array of images.

Comment: try creating a for loop and set it to loop through by the array length then use the i to get that number element in the for loop and then populating the image src using that

Comment: I'm not too keen on this method as there's going to be loads of images loaded in HTML elements. Although hidden, it will still take time to load them and this is on a Google Map so it might take a while to load.